# Как микшировать и обрабатывать аудиофайлы на сервере (LINUX, PHP)

Tags: php, аудио

Задача: на сервере автоматически смикшировать 2 аудиофайла (объединить, наложить один на другой, как через микшерный пульт звуко-оператора), желательно с выравниванием громкости (сделать одинаковую громкость - по Децибеллам). Это необходимо для предоставления демо-версии перед продажей аудиофайла, на трек нужно наложить аудио-логотип, чтобы исключить использование демо-версии (я пишу музыку и хочу её продавать). При этом тайминг должен быть по основному треку, а трек с аудио-логотипом должен обрезаться. Разбираюсь в PHP на примитивном уровне. Но, если потребуется - разберусь и с более сложными конструкциями (в конкретном случае).
Не могу найти решение... Не мало поГуглив, я нашёл только получение ID-3 тегов из mp3 файлов, а так-же простую (и очевидную) PHP конструкцию "склейки" двух файлов типа $final = $mp3_1.$mp3_2; (Это работает, файлы склеиваются в один, я проверил). А ещё нашёл кучу бесполезной (устаревшей) информации от 2005-2015 годов.

Comment: А чем [PHP-FFMpeg](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg) не подходит? Много [примеров](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14498539/how-to-overlay-downmix-two-audio-files-using-ffmpeg) по его использованию и работы с чисто аудио-файлами.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное! Мне надо было гуглить на английском, не подумал)))
Пока изучаю тему. И уже возникли вопросы.
Что есть ffmpeg?
У меня сложилось впечатление, что "ffmpeg" это Linux- функция/библиотека/класс или подобное, встроенное в Linux. А "PHP-FFMpeg", это PHP-класс для удобной работы с "ffmpeg".
И примеры, приведённые вами относятся именно к "ffmpeg", а не к "PHP-FFMpeg"
На GitHub есть пояснения по работе с классом, там всё в PHP, например:
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg \FFMpeg::create();
$audio = $ffmpeg-> open ('track.mp3');
...
Поправьте, если ошибаюсь.

Comment: А если не ошибаюсь, то ещё вопрос, может подскажете, чем лучше запускать Linux-команду (ffmpeg -i background.mp3 -i ...) - 
system(command); или exec(command); или shell_exec(command); ?
На счёт установки ffmpeg на сервере, спрошу у хостера.

Comment: запускайте ffmpeg через exec(); если вам php необходим, или из консоли если php не нужен
сборки ffmpeg кастомные возможны
ffmpeg -version выведет все включенные библиотеки в сборке